# Not writing text file through command line

Tags: c, command-line, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to create a program where it saves the age, first name, and last name entered by the user in a text file, but it's not writing the text file entered through the command line. The file name is taken as a command line argument. My loop should end when the user enters 0 for the age.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char fname[30], lname[30];
    int age;

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("No file\n");
    return 0;
    }

    printf("This program reads and saves ages and names in a text file.\n");

    do {
    printf("Enter person (age, first last): ");
    scanf("%d, %s %s", &age, fname, lname);
    fprintf(fp, "%d, %s %s", age, fname, lname);
    } while  (age > 0);



    fclose (fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Why don't you check for errors? `if (fp == NULL) { handle opening error }` I bet you didn't open the file. Also remember about scanf `if (scanf(..) != 3) { handle input error }`

Comment: also you are opening the file for reading but trying to write to it

Comment: You don't check that there is an `argv[1]` before using it.  If you forgot to provide the filename argument, you will crash.

Comment: you are still opening the file for reading("r") but trying to write to it.

Comment: and what did you see when you stepped through with your debugger

Comment: Given that you demand a comma in the data, there's a fair chance you'll get user error on input.  Check the return value from `scanf()` before assuming that the data was entered OK.

Comment: Since you don't initialize `fname` and `lname`, if scanf doesn't populate them, the `fprintf` code will likely not encounter a NULL terminator in the 30 chars allocated, and try to access into memory that is not part of the process.  Also, as @pm100 points out, you need to change `fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");` into `fp = fopen (argv[1], "w");` to open the file for writing, or `fp = fopen (argv[1], "a");` to open for appending to an existing file.

Comment: @bruceg thanks I initialized them fname and lname and changed "r" to "w" and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

If the file doesn't exist, the open will fail as you are opening in read mode. When that happens, it is not checking that the open was successful, so your use of it (NULL) afterwards will cause segmentation fault.

You also mention a loop, but there is no loop here. Nor do you check for valid input